# POST requests with cookie

Tags: python, post, cookies, web, http-post

I'm trying to send post requests with payload to automate an entry. The url is: https://gleam.io/wOAtd/air-jordan-iii-free-throw-line.

```
#
payload = {
    email and address
}
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
}
r1 = requests.get(
    'https://gleam.io/wOAtd/air-jordan-iii-free-throw-line'
)
print("r1", r1.status_code)
r2 = requests.post(
    'https://gleam.io/set-contestant',
    data = payload, cookies = r1.cookies,
    headers = headers)
print("r2", r2.status_code)
```

I'm getting 200 from `r1` but 500 from `r2`. What else should I do? If you provide an answer please explain what you look for in network".

Comment: I'm afraid you can do nothing, 500 status code means - [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500), server just fails to process your request.

Comment: You should verify the 2nd url in a browser yourself first before posting the question. If the server throws you a 500 there is practically nothing you do unless you have control over the server or you can contact the admin of the server.